# let $a, b, c$ be positive integers such that $a^2 - bc$ is a square. Prove that $2a + b + c$ is not prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need help with the following problem:

let $a, b, c$ be positive integers such that $a^2 - bc$ is a square. 
Prove that $2a + b + c$ is not prime.

thanks

Comment: $$c=(a^2-k^2)/b$$

Answer (score 3):

Given $a^2-bc=n^2$, we get:
$$2a+b+c=2a+b+\frac{a^2-n^2}{b}=\frac{2ab+b^2+a^2-n^2}{b}=\frac{(a+b)^2-n^2}{b}=\\
\frac{(a+b-n)(a+b+n)}{b}.$$

Note: $a+b-n>b$ and $a+b+n>b$.

There can be three cases:

Case 1: $a+b-n=bp$, then $2a+b+c$  is divisible by $p>1$ and $a+b+n>1$.

Case 2: $a+b+n=bq$, then $2a+b+c$ is divisble by $q>1$ and $a+b-n>1$.

Case 3: $a+b-n=uv$ and $a+b+n=st$ such that $us=b$, then $2a+b+c$ is divisible by $v>1$ and $t>1$.

Comment: Where's the contradiction? I don't see it.

Comment: $2a+b+c$ is an integer and so is the final fraction. $a+b-n\ne b$ and $a+b+n\ne b$.

Comment: No, that reasoning is invalid. For example,
$$\frac{(3)(4)}{6}$$
is an integer but $3\ne 6$ and $4\ne 6$.

Comment: also, $a,b,c,n\ge 1$ and $a>1$, so $a+b+n>4$.

Comment: So, what does $a+b + n > 4$ get you?

Comment: Sorry, in general, $2a+b+c>4$. See my update above.

Comment: You're not showing a contradiction. Some words are needed in your answer to highlight what you think is a contradiction.

Comment: why not? $p,a+b+n,q,a+b-n,v,t>1$, so $2a+b+c$ is divisible by a number greater than $1$.

Comment: Ok, I follow. But I think that reasoning should go in your answer, not just in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose:

$a^2-bc=k^2$ then $(a-k)(a+k)=bc$

If $( b, c)=1 $  and $[(a-k), (a+k)]=1$, then we have:

$a-k=b$

$a+k=c$

From these relations we get:

$b+c=2a$

⇒ $2a +b+c=2a+2a=4a$

Therefore $2a+b+c$ is not prime.

It is better to put this condition
'(a, b, c)=1' in the question.

Comment: Why do you suppose that $(a,b)=1$, and why do you think that that forces $a-k=b$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a,b,c$ are positive integers such that 
\begin{align*}
&a^2 - bc = n^2\\[4pt]
&2a + b + c = p\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where $n$ is a nonnegative integer, and $p$ is prime.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Then $a^2 > n^2$, hence $a > n$.

Also, we have $c=p-2a-b$, hence
\begin{align*}
&a^2 - bc = n^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2-b(p-2a-b)=n^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2-bp-2ab+b^2=n^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2-2ab+b^2-n^2=bp\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(a+b)^2-n^2=bp\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(a+b+n)(a+b-n)=bp\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
From $(a+b+n)(a+b-n)=bp$ and $a+b+n > b$, we get $0 < a+b-n < p$.

Since $0 < a+b-n < p$, and $p$ is prime, it follows that $\gcd(p,a+b-n)=1$.

Since $\gcd(p,a+b-n)=1$, and $(a+b+n)(a+b-n)=bp$, we get $p{\,\mid\,}a+b+n$, hence $p\le a+b+n$.

Since $p \le a+b+n$, and $(a+b+n)(a+b-n)=bp$, we get $b \ge a+b - n= b+(a-n) > b$, contradiction.

Comment: what do you mean when you put the part "p∣a+b+n "

Comment: @Sam Todd: The notation $x|y$ means "$x$ divides $y$" (i.e., $y$ is a multiple of $x$), so $p|a+b+n$ means $a+b+n$ is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: On the last part of your solution where you say "b≥a+b−n=b+(a−n)>b" how is there a contradiction?

Comment: @Sam Todd: The inequality
$$b \ge a+b - n= b+(a-n) > b$$
implies $b > b$, which of course, is false.

Comment: @Sam Todd: Note that since $a > n$, we have $(a-n) > 0$.

Comment: One last question, why does the contradiction mean that p can't be prime?

Comment: @Sam Todd: The argument starts by assuming the hypothesis (the given equation), _together_ with the assumption that $p$ is prime. Once a contradiction is obtained, that shows that the assumptions can't _both_ hold. Thus, if the given equation holds, $p$ _can't_ be prime.

Comment: @Sam Todd: Note that the assumption that $p$ is prime was used to show $\gcd(p,a+b-n)=1$.